# Where can I find good tutorials on sensor circuit design?

Tags: sensor, tutorial

I'm looking for tutorials/explained examples on circuit design in general, but specifically on using various sensors.

Comment: This site might work for you: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/sensorforum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a few [here](http://extremeelectronics.co.in/category/avr-tutorials/). Mostly on ultrasonic rangefinders, rfid sensors, accelerometers, temp sensors etc. There are a few good beginner tutorials that teach about basics of working with microcontrollers, if you need.

Comment: Brilliant site - I didn't know about it. Had a look at http://extremeelectronics.co.in/avr-tutorials/interfacing-temperature-sensor-lm35/ and the pdf available for download: wow! I hope the rest of tutorials are of that standard.

Answer (score 1):

[Handbook of Modern Sensors [3rd Edition] by Jacob Fraden](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441918388)
ISBN: 1441918388

This reference book covers a number of different types of sensors and the circuits that can be used to read them.